# On "wohl" in an example sentence

Tags: meaning, modal-particle

What does *wohl* mean in the following sentence?

> Es wird wohl leider nicht zum Bestehen reichen.

Does it mean that it won't be enough to pass? Or maybe or probably it won't be enough to pass?

So, is the passing for sure or is there still doubt? And if there is a doubt, how strong is it? Is the passing almost for sure or is there just a minor chance?

Comment: This here is a board about **German** language. Any question, that requires knowledge of other languages than German to be answered, is off-topic. English is an other language than German, so if you need to have knowledge of English vocabulary to answer a question, then it is off topic.

Comment: sry, i wanna know how to use wohl, german is not my first language, i try to use an easy way to express it. like this sentence, i can understand it without wohl, but with wohl , it seems like different.

Comment: Then you didn't ask what you really wanted to know. But your question now has been edited, so you have to hope that enough people vote to reopen it, and then you probably will get an answer.

Comment: sry, do you know that means? normally i know "wohl" likes comfortable, " unwohl " i use it like uncomfortable. But at here, what it means? or can you tell me that excatlly way to understand it?

Answer (score 3):

I would see "wohl" as "probably". Somebody saying "wohl" usually thinks that something is right, but doesn't really know, so cannot be certain. On the other hand (especially in your example) he may not be allowed to say so directly (before it is officially announced) and talks slightly around the bush. All in all certainty may be about 80%.

So in your example the chance of a pass would be around 20%. -> It probably won't be enough to pass?

Answer (score 3):

The adverb *wohl* can mean *well:*

> Ich fühle mich **wohl.**
>   I feel **well.**

You find it with this meaning also i compound words:

> **wohl**geformt = **well**-formed
>   **wohl**begründet = **well**-founded
>   **wohl**genährt = **well**-fed
>   **wohl**erzogen = **well**-behaved

---

But *wohl* also can mean *maybe, perhaps, probably:*

> Er hat **wohl** recht.
>   He **probably** is right.

So, your sentence is:

> Es wird **wohl** leider nicht zum Bestehen reichen.
>   **Probably** it will not be enough to pass.

But in this context you also can translate it as *unfortunately:*

> **Unfortunately** it will not be enough to pass.

---

Dictionaries are good resources to get informed about the meaning of a word. Try [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/wohl)

Another good resource is [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wohl) (Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache = digital dictionary of German language), but you need to understand German to read it.

Also worth to look up are the synonym lists of [Woxicon](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/wohl.php). Each words belongs to one or many words that all mean the same.

Comment: *Unfortunately* is the translation of *leider*, not of *wohl*.

Comment: *wohl* compared to *will* would appear much more like a potentialis (for *o* in the anlaut compare e.g. *voluntary* or indeed *wollen*), "Das wird wohl reichen" ~ "that will be enough", instead of "well", notwithstanding "that's well enough"

Comment: I concede that "leider" ~ "unfortunately" would be an apt translation, except for the emotional subtext.